# Cards inside the carousel are displayed vertically instead of horizontal display

Tags: html, css, django

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
  <div id="demo" class="carousel slide my-3" data-ride="carousel">
      <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2" ></li>
      </ul>

      <!--Slideshow starts here -->
      <div class="container carousel-inner no-padding">

        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img src='{% static "shop/test.jpg" %}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>

          <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img src='{% static "shop/test.jpg" %}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img src='{% static "shop/test.jpg" %}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img src='{% static "shop/test.jpg" %}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>



        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img src='{% static "shop/test.jpg" %}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img src='{% static "shop/test.jpg" %}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img src='{% static "shop/test.jpg" %}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img src='{% static "shop/test.jpg" %}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img src='{% static "shop/test.jpg" %}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>

          <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img src='{% static "shop/test.jpg" %}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img src='{% static "shop/test.jpg" %}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img src='{% static "shop/test.jpg" %}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>

      <!-- left and right controls for the slide -->
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
      </a>

  </body>
</html>
```

I am using the code to get c carousel with cards being displayed horizontally however the cards are coming in a vertical manner.
I have added the bootstrap cdn as well but i don know what is wrong.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I5Cf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I5Cf.png)

I have attacthed a screenshot of how my browser looks.

Please have a look and tell me where i am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI the image you uploaded seems to be a screenshot of google asking how to screenshot?

Comment: Can you upload a minimal code example please so that we can help you

Comment: I don't understand, you want a carousel with one card per slide? Or with 4 cards per slide? In the latter case, your carousel-item is missing a `row` class attribute, as `col-3` only works inside a `row` (and you don't need to set `col-sm-3`... by the way if you want 3 columns for all sizes anyway `col-3` does the job)